# XPath - invert selection

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm writing an xpath and I wrote the xpath which matches some nodes in the document tree

But I'd like to match all the other elements instead, so I'd like to inverse the selection in the context of the whole document

So let's say we have the following xpath

```
//*[@id='menu']//*
```

and document

```
<body>
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
</div>
<div>
<div id="menu">
  <UL>
    <LI>home</LI>
    <LI>about</LI>
  </UL>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
</body>
```

so the uppercased nodes are matched, but what I want to achieve is mark all the lowercase nodes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The DIV is not matched, BTW.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original XPath expression

```
//*[@id='menu']//*
```

matches all element nodes that are descendants of the `<div id="menu">` (but *not* the `div` element itself).  Depending on exactly what you mean by the "inverse" you could try something like

```
//*[not(ancestor::*[@id='menu'])]
```

which matches all element nodes that do not have an ancestor with `id="menu"`, which would include the `div` with `id="menu"` but not its children or grandchildren.  If you want to exclude the `div` as well, use `ancestor-or-self::` instead of `ancestor::`

---

If you have XPath 2.0 then a more general answer to your original question is to look at the `except` operator - in XPath 2.0 you can say `X except Y` to select all the nodes matched by expression `X` but not also by `Y`

```
//* except //*[@id='menu']//*
```

There are also `union` (nodes matched by either `X` or `Y`) and `intersect` (both `X` and `Y`) operators.

Comment: Or change to `ancestor-or-self` if you want to exclude the DIV.

Comment: @choroba we both had the same thought at the same time :-)

Comment: We did. I was about to post the same soltuion as you did :)